# Indent in floating toc (.Rmd)

Tags: css, r-markdown

I want to have the same indent in a wrapped line of a floating table of content entry when I create a html file from a .Rmd file in RStudio, but I cant't find the right place in the .css.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/commit/7e9ec8d427daf79109c2b8d6561ef1b3f0f16349) by RStudio immediately, thank's.